# 2D Scatter Plot in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Using Three.js, I created a 3D scatter plot.  Here is an example as a fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/ynFzw/19/

I generate some random points (x, y, z) and add them to the plot.  Here is an example of the `for` loop I use to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    colors[i] = new THREE.Color(1, 1, 1);
    colors[i].setHSL(1000 / 2000, 1, 0.5);

    var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
        size: 5,
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        transparent: true,
        useScreenCoordinates: false
    });

    material.color.setHSL(1.0, 0.2, 0.7);

    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var max = 50;
    var min = -50;

    vertex.x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    vertex.y = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    vertex.z = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

    geometry.vertices.push(vertex);

}
```

In practice, the points are plotted based on values in an array.  So let's say I have a dataset that contains only x and y values (2D).  I'd still like to be able to show a plot using Three.js.

I've created a fiddle that sort of does this, by only creating an XY grid, and commenting out the z value.  But unfortunately, this seems to put the points a distance away from the grid, not directly on the grid like you would see in a typical 2D plot.  Here is my fiddle for this...

http://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/exr6xc42/1/

I know it might sound a little silly to use Three.js for a 2D plot, but I want to be able to have the option in case a dataset only has x and y values as plottable.

Based on the fiddle above, how can I get the points to appear on the grid, like a standard 2D plot?  Do I need to set the z coordinate to something specific?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused. Your 2nd fiddle has a 3-d grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it enough to change this line (line 43) from

```
gridXY.position.set(0, 0, -50);
```

to

```
gridXY.position.set(0, 0, 0);
```

?